# Php multi-dimensional array from mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a mysql table that looks like this:

```
id | uid | title     | description | parent
1  |  1  | Portraits | desc.       | photostream
2  |  1  | Abstract  | descr.      | photostream
```

and I am trying to build a multi-dimensional array that would end up looking like this:

```
Array
(
      [0]
          [id] => 1
          [uid] => 1
          [title] => Portraits
          [description] => desc.
          [parent] => photostream
      [1]
          [id] => 2
          [uid] => 1
          [title] => Abstract
          [description] => descr.
          [parent] => photostream
)
```

I am using the select query:

```
$query = mysql_query(
  "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `uid`='1' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks,
Levi

Comment: If `uid` is a numeric column, do not compare or assign it to a string (single quoted value). MySQL won't complain but you might be surprised when the cast from string to number doesn't result in the number you expected.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid = '1' ORDER BY id DESC");
$results = array();
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $results[] = $line;
}
```

Comment: $line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) for any newcomers since the mysql variation was deprecated.

Comment: For new mysql version this will work 
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid = '1' ORDER BY id DESC"; 
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

       $results = array();
    
         while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $results[] = $line;
          }

Answer (score 1):

This does not include the sql functions for gathering the data but I made a table for my issue (was the same exact problem) This is my table also by the way. So its more of example than an explanation.

**This is not a full on explanation but is a example code.**

---

**TABLE:** 
        [ ID | Parent | name |href | title ]

---

**CODE:**

```
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    if ($row['parent'] === null)
        $data[$row['id']][0]= '<a href="'.$row['href'].'"'.($row['title']!==null)?'title="'.$row['title'].'"':''.'>'.$row['name'].'</a>';
    else 
    {
        $temp = '<a href="'.$row['href'].'"'.($row['title']!==null)?'title="'.$row['title'].'"':''.'>'.$row['name'].'</a>';
        array_push($data[$row['parent']],$temp);
    }
}
```

I used this to generate my links for my navbar. Then I used a function to make a multi level list out of them. For my issue. Its very similar issue but this was my solution.

If you would like. Instead of making your own version. I can make a similar code using your database scheme for the data instead..

**Warning:** It seems this might only work on a two level layout at moment. Ill improvise code some more and post the next version of my snippet.

Answer (score -2):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid = '1' ORDER BY id DESC");
$results = array();
$num_fields=mysql_num_fields($query);
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query);
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++
{
  for($j=0;$j<$num_fields;$j++
  {

  $results[$i][$j]=$line[$i][$j];
  }

}

}
```