# Sum the value of single array based on key value

Tags: php, arrays

This question is not a duplicate of other. it is different,This is current code, I am trying to sum the values of a array based on the same key value of date.

```
foreach ($TablesArr as $tr) {
     $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
     $criteria->select = 'date,mal';
     $Arr1 = $tr::model()->findAll($criteria);
     $array_1 = array();
     foreach ($Arr1 as $a1) {
          $array_1['date'] = $a1['date'];
          $array_1['mal'] = $a1['mal'];
     }
}
```

My Current output is:

```
Array
(
    [date] => 2015-11-00
    [mal] => 35
)
Array
(
    [date] => 2015-12-00
    [mal] => 20
)
Array
(
    [date] => 2016-01-00
    [mal] => 30
)
Array
(
    [date] => 2016-01-00
    [mal] => 10
)
Array
(
    [date] => 2015-11-00
    [mal] => 50
)
```

If the `date` is same, then sum the value of `mal` in the array. For example, In the above array, the date `2015-11-00` appears twice or more than twice (5 or 10 times etc) then sum all of the values of it for that date. Currently it appears twice so for `2015-11-00` the `mal` values will be `35+50=85`. I want my output to be like this below:

```
Array
(
    [date] => 2015-11-00
    [mal] => 85
)
Array
(
    [date] => 2015-12-00
    [mal] => 20
)
Array
(
    [date] => 2016-01-00
    [mal] => 40
)
```

I have tried:

```
$result = array();

        foreach($Arr1 as $data) {
            $result[ $data['date'] ] += $data['mal'];
        }
```

Comment: @ficuscr That question doesn't need the sums grouped by another column.

Comment: Its not a duplicate of other question, I already lot of time on SOF, can't find any value that worked for me @ficuscr

Comment: Retracted. Sorry, see a lot of these and they are always `array_sum` / `array_map` solutions. Glossed over it.

Comment: You can use:
$result = array();
foreach($Arr1 as $data) {
    $result [ $Arr1 ['date'] ] += $Arr1 ['mal'];
}

Comment: @Barmar, its not a duplicate of that question too, That question answer gives me error `Illegal string offset 'date'`

Comment: @TanseerULHassan your answer gives `Undefined index: 2015-12-00`

Comment: @AsfandyarKhan You must have done something wrong, it should work. Update your question with the code you tried.

Comment: I see the problem, you're not creating `$array_1` properly. You're just overwriting it each time through the loop, not creating a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: Just use `$Arr1`, there's no need for the new array `$array_1`.

Comment: How can i create it properly then? @barmar

Comment: `$Arr1` is already created properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150999/discussion-between-asfandyar-khan-and-barmar).

Comment: @Barmar This question is not duplicate and then question you mention is other thing which sum on bases of key but his question sum on the basis of key value like data value 2015-12-00 so reopen it. Also the second array is expected result array so that is not yet created.

Comment: Related: [Create multidimensional array from database query in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52059113/2943403) and [Php multi-dimensional array from mysql result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5053857/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$array_1` variable doesn't contain all the values from the original `$Arr1` array. You're overwriting the same elements each time through the loop, so it just contains the last item from `$Arr1`. These lines:

```
$array_1['date'] = $a1['date'];
$array_1['mal'] = $a1['mal'];
```

should be:

```
$array_1[] = array('date' => $a1['date'], 'mal' => $a1['mal']);
```

Another problem is that you're resetting `$array_1` each time through the outer loop.

You can also use `array_merge` to combine the arrays, instead of the loop:

```
$array_1 = array();
foreach ($TablesArr as $tr) {
     $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
     $criteria->select = 'date,mal';
     $Arr1 = $tr::model()->findAll($criteria);
     $array_1 = array_merge($array_1, $Arr1);
}
```

You can use one of the solutions in [php group by SUM using multi dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269188/php-group-by-sum-using-multi-dimensional-array?noredirect=1&lq=1) to create an associative array with the sums grouped by date. You can turn this into a 2-dimensional array with another loop:

```
$newresult = array();
foreach ($result as $date => $mal) {
    $newresult[] = array('date' => $date, 'mal' => $mal);
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/0hqo9t)