# Create multidimensional array from database query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a database with a number of entries with data like so:

```
id  number  data
1   1       'tyfvib'
2   1       'fgdhjjd'
3   1       'gdgdhdj'
4   2       'dgfhfh'
5   2       'fghdhd'
```

So I have a unique ID and then a column with numbers and then a column with different strings.

I then have a query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$stmt = DB::run($sql);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $number= $row['number'];
    $data = $row['data'];
}
```

I want to make a multidimensional associative array which would have first of all an array of the unique numbers and these would contain an array of the data associated with them.

I had tried putting `$array[$number] = $data` inside the while loop but this obviously will just make an array where the only data associated with a number is the last one in the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I had tried putting $array[$number] = $data inside the while loop but this obviously will just make an array where the only data associated with a number is the last one in the loop.

Then add an additional set of []:

```
$array[$number][] = $data;
```

will create a new entry in the array `$array[$number]` each time.

Answer (score -1):

you need to create a array variable before your loop where you can push your data on each iteration as

```
$alldata=[]
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $alldata[$row['number']][] = $data
}
echo"<pre>";print_r($alldata);
```

Comment: square brackets suggest a 3-d array. ??